# Set multiple range, use if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with this code. Right now it's searching only in all column J, but I want it to search in all column K as well, to do the following. for example,

if

J6=0 then hide the row

J6=1 unhide row

K6=1 then hide the row

(column J is if the Job is released for manufacturing, column K is if the Job is shipped to the costumer)

To sum up if K6=1 i want the row hidden no matter what, but if K6=0 i want it to look for J6. See my code below that I got from another source (click [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2010/automatically-hide-rows-in-excel-based-on-value/17036d97-a5c9-42a2-9f2d-f53d53510da7)) It works, I just need one more option.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("J6:J" & LastRow)
   If c.Value = 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf c.Value = 1 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Or`

```
If c.Value = 0 or c.offset(0,1) = 1 Then
```

You could also stream line and remove the If.

Another note If you do not have errors in column J or column K then the use of `On Error Resume Next` is not needed.  The use of this should be used sparingly and only if no other form of error control is available.  It will hide errors that need to be addressed properly.

I left it in just encase.  But most of the time you want to know when the code errors and not cover it up.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("J6:J" & LastRow)
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = cBool(c.Value = 0 or c.offset(0,1) = 1)   
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, I don't see where it's looking in column K, can you explain?

Comment: `c.offset(0,1)` since c is in column j and column k is the next one over, offset refers to that column.